# PHP mongodb sum query

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, sum

MongoDB can not get the total.

MYSQL :

```
select sum(play) as toplam from videos
```

MongoDB :

```
    $group = $naytu->db->videos->group(array(), array("toplam" => 0), "function(obj, prev) {prev.toplam = prev.toplam + obj.play - 0;}");
```

results (print_r)

```
Array
(
[retval] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [toplam] => NAN
            )

    )

[count] => 78656
[keys] => 1
[ok] => 1
)
```

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP @Neils answer is:

```
$mongo->videos->aggregate([
    ['$group' => ['_id' => null, 'toplam' => ['$sum' => '$play']]]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [group()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) function is kind of an old form of achieving results like this, it will also **not work** with sharded collections. Better to familiarize yourself with [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    {"$group": { "_id": null, "toplam": {"$sum": "$play"} }}

]);
```

Output for you driver will just be a cursor just like using find.

for [PHP Syntax](https://www.php.net/mongocollection.aggregate)

For the record, your usage seems to be way off. Much as above you just translate the relative JSON to Dicts, and if that is still a problem then use a [JSON parser](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to show you how. All the arguments are valid JSON, so I'm reminding myself to do this for all examples now, so people can easily dump into their own language.

```
 db.collection.group({
     "key": {},
     "reduce": "function(curr, result) { result.total += curr.play;  }",
     "initial": { "total": 0 } 
 })
```

But still, don't use this anyway. Stick to aggregate, it's a useful tool to [**learn**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

Of course in **all** cases, make sure that **all** your data being applied to a sum is actually a number, or things will blow up on you.

Comment: @user3342378 See the link. Google is your friend ;)

Comment: @user3342378 if you're still struggling with this the edits should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
"function(obj, prev) {prev.toplam = new NumberInt(prev.toplam) + new NumberInt(obj.play);}"
```